# Sum two fields in a nested array in RethinkDB

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python

The following document exists in a table in RethinkDB:

```
{  
   u'destination_addresses':[  
      u'1 Rockefeller Plaza,
      New York,
      NY 10020,
      USA',
      u'Meadowlands,
      PA 15301,
      USA'
   ],
   u'origin_addresses':[  
      u'1600 Pennsylvania Ave SE,
      Washington,
      DC 20003,
      USA'
   ],
   u'rows':[  
      {  
         u'elements':[  
            {  
               u'distance':{  
                  u'text':u'288 mi',
                  u'value':464087
               },
               u'duration':{  
                  u'text':u'5 hours 2 mins',
                  u'value':18142
               },
               u'status':u'OK'
            },
            {  
               u'distance':{  
                  u'text':u'266 mi',
                  u'value':428756
               },
               u'duration':{  
                  u'text':u'4 hours 6 mins',
                  u'value':14753
               },
               u'status':u'OK'
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   u'status':u'OK'
}
```

I am trying to sum the 'value' field for both duration and distance (so, getting the total distance and duration for a given trip, which is what one of these documents is from the Google Maps Distance API). I have tried a great many combinations of pluck (from the nested fields documentation) but cannot seem to get this working. I'm working in Python, and thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
document['rows'].concat_map(lambda row: row['elements'])['distance']['value'].sum()
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be for ReQL? If so, I can't seem to get it to work and can't find a similar snippet in the documentation. And, I'm noob enough on Python to not know off-hand if it's supposed to be dropped in there?

Comment: It's ReQL code.  If you replace `document` with whatever ReQL query gets your document, then the above query is meant to sum the distances.

Comment: Gotcha, worked like a charm. I had to add a couple things to get it to work in Python interpreter, so for anyone else looking at this I ended up with: `r.table('stories').get('689bc43c-c8c3-45df-b38b-e52043a0bab4')['rows'].concat_map(lambda row: row['elements'])['distance']['value'].sum().run()` thanks @mlucy!